# Cutting audio stream into utterances

Tags: python, audio, fft, audiocontext

I want to split my frontend audio stream with python in my flask backend into utterances. In the flask backend I use the [webrtcvad](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad) python module to do this, but apparently my frame length is not the right size. I need a frame size of 10ms, 20ms or 30ms with either a sampling rate of 8k, 16k or 32k.

I think this is the problem, but I am not really sure.

In the frontend I use the `navigator.getUserMedia` as a source and take the audio from it `audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(navigator.getUserMedia)`. I feed the audio into analyser with a sampling size of 2048 samples per block.

```
analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
analyserNode.fftSize = 2048;
inputPoint.connect( analyserNode );
```

With a sample rate of 16k and a wanted frame size of 20ms (50 blocks per second), my block size should be 320. The analyser uses a fast fourier transformation where the block size can only be 2^x, which means it cant be 320.

Does anybody know how to solve my problem?

Comment: If you want to analyse a specific duration in time, but the sample count is not a power of 2 then the traditional solution is to zero-pad the data

Comment: @fdcpp but feeding my text to speech network zeros would change the output wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't say, that depends entirely on how the model was trained. If you need a specific length of time to be considered, I'm afraid your only option is to zero-pad.